# Confirm closing the app on back pressed ONLY in MainAcitity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

I want the user to confirm closing my app. I use the following code for that in my MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
        toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to close this app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
        this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } else {
        if (toast != null) {
            toast.cancel();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In other classes I use this:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mWebView.onBackPressed()) { return; }
    // ...
    super.onBackPressed(); }
```

Now I get the confirm event in EVERY class, but I only want it in my MainActivity. How can I do that?

Note: I have to extent my MainActivity in other classes. That should be the main problem to solve, but I still dont know how exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Vala, If your adding fragments to the `Activty`, then you can make use `BackSackEntryCount` of `FragmentManager` like below.

```
  int backStackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
                if (backStackCount == 1) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to close this app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

if `backstackcount` is one, it means, on pressing the back button again, remaining frgament will be popped from back stack and app will be quit.

Comment: @Vala, Is fragments are adding to ur activity container or ur calling another activity , on top of Main Activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this
**in your main activity**

```
 private boolean exit = false;
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (exit) {
        finish(); // finish activity
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }, 3 * 1000);

    }
}
```

Comment: You should not use Handler for that.

Comment: So is this a bad solution?

Comment: @Vaia in my perspective its correct you can even try it and see ,,,, when the user is in mainactivity and presses a back button a toast prompts up askingvto press back again if he really wants to exit

Comment: @Vaia did you add it in the last activity where the user can close the app by pressing back

Comment: No, only in the MainActivity class

Comment: I think the problem is that I have to extent all other classes with MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    Activity activity = this;
    if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
        if (this.lastBackPressTime < System.currentTimeMillis() - 4000) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to close this app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
            this.lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            if (toast != null) {
                toast.cancel();
            }
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: What is `activityObject`?

Comment: Hope this will help @Vaia

Comment: @Vaia Solved the problem?

Comment: I dont see your answer? @Sanoop

Comment: What about now? @Vaia

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. Still happens on all other activities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109245/discussion-between-sanoop-and-vaia).

Answer (score -1):

change other class to

```
@Override 
public void onBackPressed() {
   if (mWebView.canGoBack()) { return; }
            // ...
   super.onBackPressed(); 
}
```

Comment: With this code I cant get back in these other activities at all